# Display different account fields for my account vs public account

Tags: users

How can display/hide some fields when viewing an account that isn't the current user vs. is the current user (e.g. the users/steve vs /user)?

I want to have a public profile that shows most of the same fields but hides a few fields that only the 'current' user can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Field Permissions](http://Field%20Permissions)

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

You would want to use the view own value check and view any value unchecked.

[image]